# Remote controlled motor for quadcopter does not slow down when signal is sent

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, transistors, mosfet, motor

I am trying to build a quadcopter with an Arduino Nano. The controller consists of a Arduino Uno with a joystick and an NRF24L01 (transmitter). The quadcopter is made of an Arduino Nano, a NRF24L01 (receiver), 4 dc motors (3v-6v), 4 NMOS IRF540N (VGS(TH) 2v-4v) and an external 4 AA (1,5v each battery) battery pack to supply with power the motors.
Currently, I am testing the system with just one motor. The Nano's pins 13, 12, 11, 10 and 8 are used by nrf24L01. The gate of the NMOS is connected to pin 5 (PWM), the source to the ground and the drain to the motor which is located between the nmos and the external power rail.

Right now I have two problems:
The first is that whenever I send a signal to the Nano, the motor does not seem to slow down.
The second problem is that whenever I turn on the external power supply the Nano starts printing values twice as fast resulting in printing 0 and sometimes actually reading the proper send package.

The following is the code that I ran on the Arduino Nano.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
RF24 radio(8, 10);  // CE, CSN pins
const byte address[6] = "00001";
struct DataPacket {
  int number1;
  int number2;
  bool turnedon;
};

const int dcmotor1 = 5;  // Forward 1
//const int dcmotor2 = 4;  // Left 2
//const int dcmotor3 = 5;  // Right 3
//const int dcmotor4 = 6;  // Back 4
int input1 = 512;
int input2 = 512;
bool turnedon = false;
void setup() {
  //initiate the motors
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);  // Set the same address as the transmitter
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.startListening();
  
  //Serial.print("Setup Complete");
}
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    DataPacket receivedData;
    //char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&receivedData, sizeof(receivedData));

    //Serial.print("Received Number 1: ");
    Serial.println(receivedData.number1);
    //Serial.print("Received Number 2: ");
    Serial.println(receivedData.number2);
    //Serial.println("Received State: ");
    //Serial.println(receivedData.turnedon);
    input1 = receivedData.number1;
    input2 = receivedData.number2;
    if (receivedData.turnedon == 1) {
      
      if (input1 == 1023 && input2 == 515) {
        analogWrite(dcmotor1, 150);
      }
      else {
      analogWrite(dcmotor1, 200);
    }
    
    } 
   
  }
}
```

This is the code of the transmitter

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
RF24 radio(8, 10);                 // CE, CSN pins
const int potentiometerPin1 = A0;  // Analog pin for the first potentiometer
const int potentiometerPin2 = A1;  // Analog pin for the second potentiometer
int input1 = 512;
int input2 = 512;
const byte address[6] = "00001";
struct DataPacket {
  int number1;
  int number2;
  bool turnedon;
};
DataPacket data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();  // Sending data
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);  // Set the receiving address
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
}

void loop() {
  //const char text[] = "Hello World";
  // Read the values from the potentiometers
  data.number1 = analogRead(potentiometerPin1);
  data.number2 = analogRead(potentiometerPin2);
  data.turnedon = true;
  // Read the state of the switch (HIGH or LOW)
  //int switchState = digitalRead(switchPin);

  // Print the values to the serial monitor
  Serial.print("Potentiometer 1: ");
  Serial.print(data.number1);
  Serial.print("\tPotentiometer 2: ");
  Serial.print(data.number2);
  Serial.println("Data Sent \n");

  radio.write(&data, sizeof(data));
 }
```

Comment: The way you describe the connections to the Source & Drain of your NMOS, the 1st time you turned on the PWM signal to its Gate it would have tried to short out your power supply rails. If this really is how you have it connected, then the NMOS is probably dead.

Comment: @brhans I have connected the NMOS similarly to this video on YouTube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrJ_zLWFGFw&t=550s

Comment: Your description reads: "the drain to the external power supply rail", which is not what's shown in that video. The video shows the NMOS Drain connected to the motor, which is in turn connected to the positive supply rail.

Comment: @brhans yeah sorry for that I corrected the mistake in the description.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here, but I'll start by suggesting that you break your problem down and try to control the motor with a manual PWM setting before you try to get the radio working delivering the setpoints. You need a diode across the motor. Then get numbers being read reliably from the radio (match baud rates) before tying the two together. One step at a time. The MOSFETs you have are not logic level and they may get hot. Also you'll likely need an inertial measurement unit etc. in a flight controller at some point  if you expect it to fly in a controlled manner.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have tried both the communication of the transmitter and the receiver as well as controlling the motor separately and they worked.  The motor was indeed decreasing in speed (I did this by moving the joystick to right and whenever that happened the speed of the motor was decreasing to a predetermined amount). Also, I am not expecting this design to do anything crazy I just want It to be able to get a bit of the ground and then be able to go back, forward, left and right.

Comment: Reading raw data into a struct is fishy practice. "Arduino Nano" doesn't mean jack to me, is it an AVR MCU or a modern one? AVR should be forgiving since it won't have any struct padding, but I wouldn't assume that. Furthermore, what does the sender code look like?

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for answering. The nano is an AVR, also I updated the question with the code of the transmitter.